# how to getValue of editText on same activity in android?

Tags: android-edittext, trygetvalue

I am not been able to print value enter by the user in editText on the same activity in android

Answer (score 0):

Create editText variable for example

```
EditText e1;
TextView t1;
```

Inside your onCreate method

```
e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

t1.setText(e1.getText().toString());
```

Here editText1 and textView1 are the ids that you will specify in xml file.
So generally your taking the value from EditText and displaying it in TextView
Your Done